# Xamarin EventToCommand switch toggled

Tags: xamarin, switch-statement, behavior, eventtocommand

Hello i am trying to use EventToCommand i used prism library but i encountered little problem as described below.

MyTestSwitch_1 works fine executing ToggledCommand as it should but when i try to click on MyTestSwitch_ListView which were generated based on listview items it doesnt do anything doesnt give any exception app does not crash it just ignores EventToCommand behavior

Does anybody know what could be wrong. Thank you.

```
<StackLayout>
    <Switch x:Name="MyTestSwitch_1" IsToggled="{Binding ValueB}}">
        <Switch.Behaviors >
            <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Toggled" 
                                      Command="{Binding ToggledCommand}"/>
    </Switch.Behaviors>
</Switch>

<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ValuesList}"
        ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"

          HasUnevenRows="True"

        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"            
        RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=OneWay}"
          Margin="10">
    <ListView.Behaviors>
        <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" 
                                  Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="MyParameter" />
    </ListView.Behaviors>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Id}" 
               Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Value}" 
               Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"/>
                    <Switch x:Name="MyTestSwitch_ListView" IsToggled="{Binding ValueB}}">
                        <Switch.Behaviors >
                            <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Toggled" 
                                  Command="{Binding  ToggledCommand}, Source={x:Reference ThisPage}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                        </Switch.Behaviors>
                    </Switch>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Comment: i have just found out that it doesnt even with button when i add it to itemtemplate it just ignores click event or toggle event...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have reference to the ViewModel. As command is its property.
Something like this:

```
Command="{Binding Path=ViewModel.PermissionGroupSelectCommand, Source={x:Reference invitationPage}}"
```

where Source is referencing the name of the current page and Path referencing command on ViewModel

Answer (score -1):

Hello i have finally found the solution at this thread

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84190/listview-binding-command

thanks to NMackay

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)